# Conditional independent variable in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

First time on Cross Validated, so here goes. I am running a logistic regression where I am trying to predict the occurrence or non-occurrence of an event.  I have a number of independent variables, two of them are not independent from each other - the presence and absence of a valve (categorical variable) and the size of that valve (double-precision floating-point variable).  Because the size of the valve is dependent on the presence of a valve, for records where there is no valve present, the size is NA/missing.  Obviously this is a problem because we have missing data - although it's intentionally missing, not missing due to randomness.

Here is my question - I am assuming I should not include both the presence of a valve and the size of the valve as variables in the model.  Therefore, is the best approach in this case to bin valve size to 'small', 'medium', 'large', and have the category 'none' to account for the absence of valves? This would mean treating size as a categorical variable. Maybe logistic regression is a sub-optimal analysis framework?

Comment: Binning a continuous predictor is certainly one approach, but it isn't advisable as it can create residual confounding.  Depending on the application, you could ignore the presence/absence variable and instead use the valve size with 0 representing no value.  Using 0 to indicate no value essentially removes the effect of value from the estimate all together.  Could you say more about the process you are trying to model?

Comment: @DemetriPananos that's a good point to consider. Your solution seems to solve the problem.  My next issue was how to bin appropriately! I think 0 values would be appropriate as they are not really missing values we are trying to impute.  Yes, the process is to predict pipe leaks in a network as a function of valves, valve size, material, and other categorical and continuous variables. Because it either leaks or doesn't leak, I am using binomial logistic regression.